# Airflow HTTP providers HttpSensor and SimpleHttpOperator not working as expected

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Airflow version: 2.3.0

API(s) used - https://gorest.co.in/

connection - gorest_httpsensor_test connection is setup as https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/

#### testdag.py

```
import datetime
import json

from airflow.decorators import dag, task

from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator


@dag(
    dag_id="test_http_provider",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 22),
    catchup=False,
    schedule=None
)
def test_http_provider():
    @task()
    def test_http_sensor():
        task_is_api_active = HttpSensor(
            task_id='is_api_active',
            http_conn_id='gorest_httpsensor_test',
            endpoint='posts/'
        )

    @task()
    def test_simplehttp():
        SimpleHttpOperator(
            task_id="http_sensor_check",
            http_conn_id="gorest_httpsensor_test",
            endpoint="posts/",
            method="GET",
            response_filter=lambda response: json.loads(response.text),
            log_response=True
        )
```

#### cmd-to-test -

#### `airflow tasks test test_http_provider test_simplehttp 2023-08-22`

#### Logs

====================

[2023-08-22T16:07:14.719+0530] {taskinstance.py:1545} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='airflow' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='test_http_provider' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='test_simplehttp' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-08-22T00:00:00+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='airflow_temporary_run_2023-08-22T10:37:14.677136+00:00'
[2023-08-22T16:07:14.720+0530] {init.py:117} DEBUG - Preparing lineage inlets and outlets
[2023-08-22T16:07:14.720+0530] {init.py:158} DEBUG - inlets: [], outlets: []
[2023-08-22T16:07:14.720+0530] {python.py:183} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-08-22T16:07:14.720+0530] {init.py:75} DEBUG - Lineage called with inlets: [], outlets: []
[2023-08-22T16:07:14.720+0530] {taskinstance.py:1356} DEBUG - Clearing next_method and next_kwargs.

====================

Expected result -
I am referring to https://betterdatascience.com/apache-airflow-rest-api/ and same command gets json output to logs, but i get no output and just says Info: Done, returned value was None.

cmd-to-test - `airflow tasks test test_http_provider test_simplehttp 2023-08-22`

Expected result -
I am referring to https://betterdatascience.com/apache-airflow-rest-api/ and same command gets json output to logs, but i get no output and just says Info: Done, returned value was None.

Note: I have tested it on browser to https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/posts and i get json response, so my connection or vpn all seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

adding @task decorator its like define a PythonOperator.

what you are doing here it to create a python operator that only define HttpSensor and SimpleHttpOperator but not actually run it. thats why you get None in the result. you don't need the @task decorator here.

```
task_is_api_active = HttpSensor(
    task_id='is_api_active',
    http_conn_id='gorest_httpsensor_test',
    endpoint='posts/'
)

http_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id="http_sensor_check",
        http_conn_id="gorest_httpsensor_test",
        endpoint="posts/",
        method="GET",
        response_filter=lambda response: response.json(),
        log_response=True
    )

(task_is_api_active >> http_task)
```

Comment: great, @SwaroopGovindaraj, can u please accept the answer. 10x